# Don't clear camera flag in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working with the WebGLRenderer in three.js and I need the camera in motion to not clear as in this video * (4:00),
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWHGW_r9EvI&feature=youtu.be&t=236

How can i do this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your instance of `WebGLRenderer` like so:

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
renderer.autoClearColor = false;
```

`preserveDrawingBuffer` is a WebGL context parameter. If set to `true`, the default framebuffers will not be cleared and will preserve their values. By telling the renderer not to automatically perform clear operations, you should get the expected result. This approach is used in one of the official examples:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_trails

`three.js R110`

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry can you tell me if there is a method to do this for one object

Comment: You could try to render a single object into a render target without clearing it and then blend it onto your scene. However, this is advanced stuff and not easy to do for a beginner. You might want to get familiar with render targets first.